# Excluding anchor tags starting with fragment URLs using regex

Tags: php, regex

One of the WordPress plugins we're using is relying on regex to detect anchor tags in HTML. The code is as follows:

```php
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";

preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $string, $matchArray);
```

This results in `$matchArray` being populated with all anchor tags including the ones with just fragment URLs in `href` attribute (ex: `href="#this-is-an-id"` or `href="#"` shouldn't match).

We're trying to update the regex to ignore anchor tags with fragment URLs. I tried the following regex, but it seem to work. Regex is not my strong suit, looking for any helpful guidance in the right direction.

```php
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"[^#.*]??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
```

P.S.: The goal is to fix this and submit a PR to the original plugin author, so it gets rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to ignore URLs that start with `#`, you can use this:

```
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^#\"][^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYyOOe/1)